# How would you graph this circle in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I fairly new to using LaTeX so I would greatly appreciate some help.
I am trying to graph this circle here. I want my code to include the x and y axis, the ticks with the numbers, and the grid.

My code so far is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5]

\tkzGrid[color=gray]

\tkzAxeXY[very thick]

\tkzGrid

\draw[black, thick] (O) circle (2 cm);

 \draw [fill=black] (1,-1) circle (2.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can't seem to move my circle to the fourth quadrant so any guidance would help me tremendously!

[image]

Comment: Your code is OK. Only change the `\draw[black, thick] (O) circle (2 cm);` to `\draw[black, thick] (1,-1) circle (2 cm);`.